# Python initialize variables with default data for multiple objects

Tags: python, class, oop, object, constructor

I want to initialize variables with default values in a constructor without parameters, like this:

```
class Persons()
   def __init__(self):
      self.name="Joan"

p1=Persons()
print(p1.name)
```

So the result for this, will be "Joan". It will print the name of the person. All good. But how do I do this for multiple objects? I want to print `p2.name`, `p3.name`, with different names, just like above.

I got this from an exercise that asks me to "create a constructor without parameters that initializes variables with default data".

Comment: "I want to print p2.name , p3.name, with different names" - if you want all the objects to use default values, then they're all going to have the same name.

Comment: You could choose at random from a list: `self.name = random.choice(["Joan", "Alice", "Bob", ...]`, but then there's no guarantee (even ignoring the case of creating more objects than there are available names) that each instance will have a unique name.

Comment: Does the exercise actually say that the instance variable needs to be initialized differently each time?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your class can provide a set of possible names, you can create an object from which each call to `Person.__init__` gets a different name. For example:

```
from itertools import cycle

class Person:
    names = cycle(["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dan"])

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = next(Person.names)
```

Add as many names to the pool as desired.

Names will necessarily repeat once the initial set of names is exhausted and the cycle begins again. With a little more work, we can at least vary the order in which names are produced on each cycle:

```
from itertools import cycle
import random


class Person:
    def shuffled_cycle(names):
        while True:
            random.shuffle(names)
            yield from names

    names = shuffled_cycle(["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dan"])

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = next(Person.names)
```

Of course, if repeated names aren't a concern, just call `random.choice` from inside `__init__`. This is much simpler:

```
import random


class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = random.choice(["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dan"])
```

Taken to its extreme, just generate random names from a primordial soup of letters:

```
import random
import string

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        k = random.randint(3, 10)
        self.name = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, k)).title()
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add name as a parameter:

```
class Persons()
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
p1=Persons(“Joan”)
print(p1.name)
```

Or

```
p1.name = “Jim”
```

Comment: yes, that would work, but the exercise said that the constructor should have no parameters, and in this case there is one parameter: " name "

Answer (score -2):

So the thing is you want to initialize with default values, The code you wrote is correct.Every new instance of "Person" class  will initialize with the same default value which is good coding practice.Since it is "default" value thus same. However for the sake of knowledge I have written a small program that can give new names to 5 new instances of class Person however do not use this in production as it is a bad practice but good for learning.

```
class Person :
    #class Variable
    name_list=["Jhon","Naruto","James","Smith","Neo"]
    instance_count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        #Resets instance count when instances become greater that 5
        instance_count = instance_count%5  

        #Sets new name
        self.name = name_list[instance_count]

        #increment instance_count
        instance_count = instance_count + 1
```